# JS Validation with Decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript-decorator

I'm trying to build a model in TypeScript that exploits the decorators used as Data Annotation to perform some kind of Data Validation. Basically, with the following cnde:

```
function IsString(target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) : any {
  // NOTE: This should be called each time the property is set.
}

class Person { 
  @IsString
  name : string  = '';

  @IsString
  surname : string  = '';

  constructor(name: string, surname: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}

let foo = new Person('pippo','pluto');

foo.name = 'paperino'; // Validation should run, and be OK
foo.name = 7; // Validation should run, and somehow warn me
```

I would like to run the `IsString` validation each time I set the properties `name` and `surname`.

I tried different thing, like using a Proxy to intercept the `set` of each property, but then I have no clue on how I could run the different decorator. Let me show you again:

```
const PersonProxied = (name, surname, classGenerator: { new(name, surname): any }) => new Proxy(new classGenerator(name, surname), validator);

let validator = {
  set: function(obj: any, prop: any, value: any) {
    console.log(obj);
    obj[prop] = value;

    // NOTE → Here, I should run the decorator defined for property obj[prop].

    return true;
  }
}

let foo = PersonProxied('pippo','pluto', Person);
```

With this configuration, I manage to intercept every time a `Person` property changes. Though, inside the `validator` I don't know how (or if it's even possible) access the decorators for the given property.

If I'm correct, the problem is that the `IsString` function is called just once for the class prototype, and not for each instance of `Person`. So, it cannot run properly the validation on the instance of the class.

At this point, I don't know if this is even possible. I mean, I think it is, because looking online, I've found some libraries that works like this, but I would like to implement the algorithm myself, and mostly, understanding how it would work.

P.S. I still do not know how I could maintain the validation state of each property. Probably, I could just have an object inside `Person`, something like:

```
class Person {
  ...
  validatation = {
    name: { hasError: true, errors: ['error1','error2'] },
    surname: { hasError: false }
  };
  ...
}
```